# Extract the first (AND) the last characters from a string Rstudio

Tags: r

I Have to extract from a database db the first and the last letters of the column Name, while the other substract with the character "*".
From this database:

```
Name     Age
John     30
David    10
Paul     60
```

I want to have this

```
d$Name2
J***n
D****d
P***l
```

I have from now this code to extract the first and last letters, now i have to substr the other with "*" and merge all this three parts in a single column.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please post your code to show what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another solution:

Data:

```
str <- c("jasmine", "alb", "francesca", "dario", "saseelah")
```

The solution is in three steps:

First extract the initial letter of the names using backreference:

```
initial <- gsub("(^\\w)(\\w+)(\\w$)", "\\1", str)
```

Second extract the final letter of the names using backreference:

```
final <- gsub("(^\\w)(\\w+)(\\w$)", "\\3", str)
```

**EDIT**:

In both the first and the second step we make use of capturing groups, dividing the strings into chunks, and of backreference to 'recollect' these chunks. For example, to extract the `initial` letter, we capture the first letter via the anchor `^` in the capturing group `(^\\w)` and refer back to this group with `\\1` in `gsub`'s replacment argument. Thereby the initial gets included in the replacement whereas the remainder of the string gets excluded (as we don't refer to the other two capturing groups).
Backreference works analogously in extracting the final letter: there we refer back to the third capturing group with `\\3` but not to any other group thereby excluding these other groups.

Finally `paste` the initial and final letters together separating them by as many `*` as there are characters in the name minus 2:

```
library(stringr)
paste0(initial, str_dup("*", str_count(str)-2), final)
[1] "j*****e"   "a*b"       "f*******a" "d***o"     "s******h"
```

**EDIT 2**:

If the names are part of a dataframe and you want to anonymize only those names that meet a certain condition specified in another column, as you suggest in a comment, then this should work:

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  name = c("jasmine", "alb", "francesca", "dario", "saseelah"),
  status = c("employed", "unemployed", "employed", "unemployed", "employed"),
  stringsAsFactors = F
)
```

Solution:

```
initial <- gsub("(^\\w)(\\w+)(\\w$)", "\\1", df$name) 
final <- gsub("(^\\w)(\\w+)(\\w$)", "\\3", df$name)

df$anonymized <- ifelse(df$status=="employed", 
                        paste0(initial, str_dup("*", nchar(df$name)-2), final),
                        df$name)
```

Result:

```
df
       name     status anonymized
1   jasmine   employed    j*****e
2       alb unemployed        alb
3 francesca   employed  f*******a
4     dario unemployed      dario
5  saseelah   employed   s******h
```

Comment: Thank you @Chris Ruehlemann, it worked well! However I still dont' understand the code for initial and final with gsub. I've implement them like this: initial<-substr(x,1,1);
final<-substr(x,nchar(x),nchar(x)); and then used paste0 like you'd suggested, was very helpfull thank you!

Comment: That's fine. Your code works just as well as mine. I'll edit my post to provide some explanation of how I use `gsub`. Also, if the answer did help you do consider accepting it.

Comment: Since you were very kind and I think you're very good with R I take this opportunity to ask you another question about the same problem: I've another column with the occupational condition, and with cycle for I want to do the same operation but according to the values of that column, and if that column is=='employed' i want name with first and last letter with in the middle ***, otherwise i want the normal name. Example John is Employed so i want J***n, other name remain the same. Thank you very much

Comment: @Andrea I've updated the answer. If that answers your question please accept the answer by clicking the green tick in the left upper corner!

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution with the rebus package for regular expressions would be this:

```
library(rebus)
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
library(stringi)

df <- data.table::fread("Name     Age
                      John     30
                      David    10
                      Paul     60")

pattern_1 <- START %R% capture(ANY_CHAR) 
pattern_2 <- capture(ANY_CHAR) %R% END


df %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(INI = stringr::str_extract(Name, pattern_1),
                STARS = nchar(Name)-2,
                FIN = stringr::str_extract(Name, pattern_2)) %>% 
  dplyr::transmute(Age = Age,
                Name = paste0(INI, strrep("*", STARS), FIN))

   Age  Name
1:  30  J**n
2:  10 D***d
3:  60  P**l
```